# how to insert string to given string in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i am having one string `test1string` i need to pad three zeros before every digit.the result string should be `test0001string`.I have tried PAD,regexp_instr but i didn't get the correct  result.can anybody explain me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions149.htm#SQLRF06302):

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_replace('test1string', '([[:digit:]])', '000\1') tx FROM dual;

TX
--------------
test0001string
```